# Finding the Cardinal of the transitive functions group

Tags: calculus

I got 2 questions:

How do I find the cardinal of the transitive functions From N to N?

I tried to used CBS. That the Cardinal of this group is <= to the cardinal R

But how do I prove the opposite direction?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean transitive relations on $\Bbb N$?  Otherwise, what is a transitive function?  What is CBS?

Answer (score 0):

A common way to prove you have $2^{\aleph_0}$ of something is to find an infinite set of choices to make.  If you are talking about transitive relations on $\Bbb N$, can you find two transitive relations on a two element set?  Then divide $\Bbb N$ into pairs and you can choose which of the transitive relations you use on each pair independently.  You have exhibited $2^{\aleph_0}$ transitive relations.  There are many more, but you have the bound you need.

Comment: Hey,  The question was what is the the cardinal of the transitive N-->N functions group. I showed that This group is <= 2ℵ0 . Now according to CBS i need to prove the opposite but i couldnt find a one to one function to prove that.

Comment: I still do not know what a transitive function is.  I know what a transitive relation is, and suggested a way to find continuum many of those.